# Can I use repeat statements in data?

Tags: javascript

Is this possible?

I want to create continuous object data.

- what i want

  ```
    return [
        { text: '2', align: 'center', value: '2', sort: false },
        { text: '3', align: 'center', value: '3', sort: false },
        { text: '4', align: 'center', value: '4', sort: false },
        { text: '5', align: 'center', value: '5', sort: false },
        { text: '6', align: 'center', value: '6', sort: false },
        { text: '7', align: 'center', value: '7', sort: false },
        { text: '8', align: 'center', value: '8', sort: false },
    ]
  ```
- my think

  ```
    return [
        () => {
            for (let i = 0; i >= 8; i++) {
                return {
                    text: i,
                    align: 'center',
                    value: i >= 10 ? `day${i}` : `day0${i}`,
                    sort: false,
                }
            }
        },
    ]
  ```

But this, of course, did not work. How can I do it this way?

Comment: Create the array in a loop and  *then* return it

Comment: Your for loop is also problematic: do you mean `i <= 35`? This isn't a Vue-specific question, but rather a generic JS one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by filling an empty array of however many elements you want and then using `map` and the index of each empty item:

```js
const result = new Array(35).fill(0).map((_, i) => ({
  text: i,
  align: 'center',
  value: i >= 10 ? `day${i}` : `day0${i}`,
  sort: false,
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a small helper function that calls a function for (*maps over*) a given range of integers, like so:

```
function mapRange(min, max, fn) {
  const out = [];
  for (let i = min; i < max; i++) {
    out.push(fn(i));
  }
  return out;
}
```

Then you can simply

```
const result = mapRange(0, 35,  (i) => ({
  text: i,
  align: 'center',
  value: i >= 10 ? `day${i}` : `day0${i}`,
  sort: false,
}));
```

(According to a JSBench test, this is about 20% faster than Jamiec's similar solution using the `new Array().fill().map()` idiom.)

Comment: ...and without the extra function call (ie, a simple loop filling an array) it would be faster still. What's your point? on any array less than at least a few hundred thousand records we're talking the difference of nanoseconds

Comment: That if you want a map-like idiom, this is a bit faster :)

Answer (score -1):

The other answers are too long... useless... Try

```
[...Array(7)].map((_, i) => ({ text: `${i+2}`, align: 'center', value: `${i+2}`, sort: false }));
```

Comment: the shortest code is not always the easiest to read code